# excel vba increment a range

Tags: excel, range, auto-increment, sumifs, vba

```
For i = 10 to 21

    c = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Worksheets("Input").Range("J:J"), Worksheets("Input").Range("A:A"), "Sales ValueExternal", Worksheets("Input").Range("H:H"), "Europe")

Next i
```

in the this code I want to incremment the Range("J:J") from "J:J" to "U:U".
I tried it with `Cells` :

```
c = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Worksheets("Input").Cells(1, i), Worksheets("Input").Range("A:A"), "Sales ValueExternal", Worksheets("Input").Range("H:H"), "Europe")
```

and  I got an error

I tried it with `Range(Chr(Asc("J")+1)` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, keeping your syntax, would be to change `Range("J:J")` to `Columns(i)`

```
For i = 10 to 21

    c = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Worksheets("Input").Columns(i), Worksheets("Input").Range("A:A"), "Sales ValueExternal", Worksheets("Input").Range("H:H"), "Europe")

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it solve your problem but the Syntax for an For-Loop in VBA is:

```
Dim i as Integer
For i=0 To 20 Step 1

Next
```

Comment: ´Thanks, but i have a Problem just to increment the range, My For-Loop is working correctly

Comment: Then try not to use letters for the range like "J:J" you can use the "y-x-coordinates" instead. out of the for loop you declare two variables representative for the column and row index of that cell. And in the for loop you increment them before/after using them. Maybe the error could help me to finding your problem.

Comment: can you give me a example pls

Comment: `Dim i as Integer
Dim x as Integer
Dim y as Integer
x= 5
y= 6
For i=0 To 20 Step 1
 ThisWorbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(y,x).Value = “test”
 x = x + 1
 y = y + 1
Next` But the error message you receive could be important so please add it to your question.